# What is the best way to allow multiple processess to modify a lucene

Tags: lucene.net

What is the best way to allow multiple processess to modify  a lucene.NEt index without locking or conflicts?

What is the code used to add "locking" to directories so that multiple sources can modify/search the index with no interferance?

I would like to make it as resilient as possible.

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kene, 
Is quering the index considered  as "changing" the index? can I run multiple searches from different processes while i am writing to the index (populating) using another single process?

Comment: No - querying does not modify the index.  You can have any number of processes with open index reader objects while another process is making changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene does not allow multiple processes to modify an index simulatneously.  If you have multiple processes that want to modify a lucene index, your options are:

1. Implement a server that modifies the index and serves requests from other processes.
2. Use Solr to do the above.
3. Write the modifications to a queue, and run a batch process to read the queue and modify the index.